# How can I have asp.net side by side with php?

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an asp.net mvc3 website.  It replaced an older php website.  Many people have parts of the site bookmarked in reference to the .php locations and I would like to add those back into the asp.net site as simple forwards to the new location.  So mysite/product.php would redirect to mysite/usermap/product.cshtml for example.  When I insert the product.php into the directory and use an anchor href to it, I am prompted to open it with a certain program or save it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make a small redirection controller, and add a route to match something like `mysite/{id}.php`.

Then in that controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    return RedirectToActionPermanent("Product", "YourExistingController", id);
}
```

---

**edit**

In your global.asax.cs file

```
public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    // you likely already have this line
     routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // assuming you have a route like this for your existing controllers.
    // I prefixed this route with "mysite/usermap" because you use that in your example in the question
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default",
        "mysite/usermap/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    // route to match old urls
    routes.MapRoute(
        "OldUrls",
        "mysite/{oldpath}.php",
        new { Controller = "OldPathRedirection", action = "PerformRedirection", oldpath = "" }
    );
}
```

Then you would define an `OldPathRedirectionController` (`Controllers/OldPathRedirectionController.cs` most likely)

```
public class OldPathRedirectionController : Controller
{
    // probably shouldn't just have this hard coded here for production use.
    // maps product.php -> ProductController, someotherfile.php -> HomeController.
    private Dictionary<string, string> controllerMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "product", "Product" },
        { "someotherfile", "Home" }
    };

    // This will just call the Index action on the found controller.
    public ActionResult PerformRedirection(string oldpath)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldpath) && controllerMap.ContainsKey(oldpath))
        {
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", controllerMap[oldpath]);
        }
        else
        {
            // this is an error state. oldpath wasn't in our map of old php files to new controllers
            return HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I cleaned that up a little from the original recommendation. That hopefully should be enough to get you started! Obvious changes are to not hardcode the map of php filenames to mvc controllers, and perhaps altering the route to allow extra params if you require that.

Comment: Although this was not what I had in mind, it looks more like best practice then manually inserting .php files.  Can you expand a little?  Especially on what definition I would need for the route?

Comment: Thank you very much rejj! I really appreciate the effort you put into this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using IIS7 the Url rewrite module is great.  Here is the page: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

> When I insert the product.php into the directory and use an anchor href to it, I am prompted to open it with a certain program or save it. Any ideas?

Update the handler mappings manually.  However I am pretty sure when you install PHP for IIS (http://php.iis.net/) it will do it for you.

Comment: Yes, my development server did not have php installed so that was the problem, thank you.  However, the production server has it and so this issue has been resolved.

Comment: And what about the Url rewrite?  Lots of folks have used it successfully.

Comment: I do not have enough access to IIS on the production server to install Url rewrite unfortunately.  It looks like a useful tool, but I am going to have to use an implementation which is code or filesystem based.

Comment: Well once its installed by an admin (or whatever) your Url rewrites can be defined at your application's web.config level.

Answer (score 1):

Install PHP into IIS using this site.  http://php.iis.net/

Comment: This is representative of my problem.  I am developing in a different environment than the deploy environment and did not have PHP support. On deployment it works fine for me, thank you for the tip though.

Comment: just install it on your dev environment then.

Comment: There will be no functionality to the .php or I would.  So long as it works on the production server it is fine. Thanks for pointing out the obvious because I miss it sometimes - I wouldn't have checked the production server without your suggestion.