# How to find out what URL the app is operating on?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-6

I am writing a small ASP.NET MVC app.  I need to know what URL the app is operating on (e.g. is it my dev box, qa or production).

The reason is that the app sends out invites and I'd like to point the recipient to the proper box.

Is there a way to do this with ASP.NET MVC?  Or do i have to embed these things in the web.config?
P.S. The app is running under IIS6 in production and in II7 elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried "Request.Url.OriginalString"?

Answer (score 0):

Inside of global.asax.cs (unless you are on vb) there is a method `Register_Routes`. This method gets called at the very beginning of the request handling by MVC. It is possible here to dissect the route for parameters. There is some information on routing here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/02/asp-net-mvc-3-optional-parameter-routing-issue.aspx Otherwise, just google it as it is a broad topic. You may also find the answer in this question ( [How can I have asp.net side by side with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8705395/1026459) )helpful for how to handle routes with custom controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can always start from HttpContext.Current.Request and have a look at the current URL. If you found a known string you could say its on a particular environment. E.g qa.someapp.com contains 'qa.' so it is a qa environment.